# How to use CSS in Bootstrap to load a logo in the nav-brand class and have it centred?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

So here is a link to my site [CLICK HERE](http://www.newbrightonweatherstation.co.uk/theteam1.html)

I have used a random logo i found to demo what I am trying to do.
As can be seen the logo in not centred vertically in the navbar

I used code the folowing code to produce the nav bar

```
<!-- Start navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NBWS</a> -->
    <a class="navbar-brand pull-left">
    <a href="#"><img class = "brand" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/sprc-www/img/logo.png" alt="SparkCharger" /></a>
    </a>

      <!-- Dropdown menu -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="forecast.html">Forecast</a></li>
        <li><a href="Links.html">Links</a></li>
      </ul>  
      <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">About <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="theteam.html">The Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="thisstation.html">The Weather Station</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

and this custom css to resize the image

```
/* Important for logo */
.brand {height: 25px;}
```

any ideas how to centre the image?

Comment: Add img.brand {margin-top: 13px;} to your about.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now add `line height` in your **anchor** link and `Display inline-block` **as like this**

```
.navbar-brand.pull-left+a {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
line-height: 50px;
}
```

**Result is this**

[image]